# How to get DATE column in SQL Server in mm/dd/yyyy format and export it to CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, date, datetime

I have a requirement to store data in a column in SQL Server with mm/dd/yyyy format. Which in my mind I would create this column with `DATE` datatype and use `CONVERT()` to convert it in mm/dd/yyyy format

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].TempDate 
(
    CompanyID nvarchar (512) NULL,
    VacDate date NULL,
    OffDate date NULL,
    Duration time NULL
)

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), VacDate, 10) AS "StartDate"
FROM [dbo].TempDate;
```

No issues, I get the date in mm/dd/yyyy format. The problem is that I need to then import this table to CSV format and the date in the table is in its standard yyyy-mm-dd and so that's what gets imported in CSV. I need the date in CSV to be in mm/dd/yyyy format. I tried to `INSERT` into this table with `CONVERT`, but the date doesn't convert. Is there a way to STORE DATE in mm/dd/yyyy column right out of the gate? Like in Oracle its possible to define the column in a certain format.

Thank you for any thoughts on this.

Comment: A `date` has no format, nor needs one. Which is why you are (correctly) using a `convert` to give it that format for display purposes. When I say correctly I mean that the use of `convert` per se is correct, even though you are not calling it correctly. The style 10 is `mm-dd-yy`, not `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is made for such tasks.

Comment: I am using this in azure and I need to basically get this date column in mm/dd/yyyy format in CSV. I cannot use SSIS in Azure data factory

Comment: Once again - dates in a date (or similar) column have no defined format. They are stored as binary values that are unreadable. Whatever "format" you see in a CSV file is a product of the tool you are using to generate that file. If your goal is to force the use 
of a particular format in your CSV file, try searching the internet for suggestions about how to export dates in a particular format using ADF. But if the issue is about what you "see" when you query the database, the format is also a product of the tool you use for that. The column itself has **no format**.

Answer (score 0):

While I believe your focus should be on the query that is getting the data for the export, if you really need it in the database you could add a computed column that displays a string representation of the data, and use that column for the export.

```
Alter table TempDate
Add VacDataComputed As CONVERT(varchar(10), VacDate, 10)
```

Edit: As mentioned, you are using 10 for the style parameter, which will render `mm-dd-yyyy`.  If you want it in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, use 101.  You can see more style formats [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp).

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants 101 and not 10

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I thought so too, and was going to put it in the answer....but I was a little confused as his posted SQL code had it with 10.  But you are correct, if OP or anyone else wants a date in format `mm/dd/yyyy`, 101 would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Do you mean the CSV file contains `MM/dd/yyyy` format, and you want to import that into the SQL table as datetime values? So values like `12/31/2015`, `07/15/2014` etc. are in the csv data file?

If that is the case I think you have two options.

1. Either impport the datetime column as string values, and then add a new column with datetime datatype and convert the values using string manipulation.
2. or, just change the CSV input file and reformat the datetime column before importing it, using Notepad++ [CSV Lint plug-in](https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint) or Python or something